# Why can't I send emails with my domain name emails without deliverability issues?

Tags: email, authentication, email-address, dkim

I have separate my website and email hosting. I use yandex smail service for email hosting. Everytime I send and email to an address, I get no dkim authentication issue even though, I have configured spf, dkim and dmarc in my dns zone.

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: For example, if I send you an email and you have a gmail account, you will receive my email with a question mark instead of an unknown avatar and when you hover the avatar it will say: "Gmail couldn't verify that [my domain] actually sent this message (and not a spammer). "

Comment: One tip: look at the mail headers, Gmail will also add its own and there may some clues as to why they determine your mail cannot be "verified". I don't even know it means for Google, may it's not about DKIM but something else. I'm afraid there is not enough information to help you. What would help is the domain name, so we can check the DNS records, and the IP addresses you're sending from. Alternatively there are free DKIM testing services online.

Comment: What is the domain so I can check the records?

Comment: The domain is duff.ml

Comment: I've tested tested it with the https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/dkim/dkim-check/ and it worked. It still doesn't work on gmail though.